# Invalid implicit conversion from bytes32 to bytes memory requested

Tags: solidity, remix, multisignature

Error in given code,

Invalid type for argument in function call.

```
 return ecrecover(operationHash, v, r, s);
```

And,

```
 function sendMultiSigToken (address toAddress, uint value, address tokenContractAddress, uint expireTime, bytes signature, uint sequenceId) public onlySigner{
    //verify the other signer
    var operationHash = keccak256("ERC20", toAddress, value, tokenContractAddress, expireTime, sequenceId);

  //error in verifyMultiSig's operationHash argument

    verifyMultiSig(toAddress, operationHash, signature, expireTime, sequenceId);
    EERC20Interface erc20instance = EERC20Interface(tokenContractAddress);
    if(!erc20instance.transfer(toAddress, value)){
        revert();
    }
}
```

How to solve these errors? I am using 0.4.10 version compiler.

Comment: What is the signature of verifyMultiSig? Your solc version is too old I'd encourage to use a newer version since v0.4.22 you have available abi.encodePacked https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.22/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-functions, that you can use to convert any type to bytes.

Comment: `function verifyMultiSig(address toAddress, bytes32 operationHash, bytes signature, uint expireTime, uint sequenceId) private returns (address){

        var otherSigner = recoverAddressFromSignature(operationHash, signature);

    }`